# "Lamp-switch set-up number" of $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, hypergraph, covering

**Motivation.** The following has a real-life (!) inspiration from a discussion about how to connect lamps and switches in an efficient way.

**Question.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer and let $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ represent $n$ lamps, each of which is in exactly one of the states OFF or ON. Let $E\subseteq {\cal P}(\{1,\ldots,n\})$. For every $e\in E$ we have an "*$e$-button*", such that if that button is pressed, every element of $e$ switches its state (either from OFF to ON, or vice versa). We say that $E$ is *state-complete* if the following condition holds:

> If all lamps are OFF and if $k\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ is given, there is a finite button-sequence $e_1, \ldots, e_m \in E$ such that after all the buttons have been pressed, lamp $k$ is ON and all other lamps are OFF.

For instance, $\big\{\{k\}: k\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\big\}$ is state-complete, and $\big\{\{1,\ldots,n\}\big\}$ is not state-complete for $n\geq 2$.

Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, what is the least cardinality that a state-complete set $E\subseteq {\cal P}(\{1,\ldots,n\})$ can have?

Comment: Think of $\mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n\}$ as an $n$-dimensional vector space over the $2$-element field. You're asking for the minimal size of a set $E$ whose linear combinations include all the standard basis vectors $\{k\}$. Such an $E$ spans the whole space, so the minimum size is $n$.

Comment: Or, more elementary, if you have $k<n$ buttons, you get at most $2^k<2^n$ combinations of lamps, thus not all. This contradicts to the possibility to switch each separate lamp.

Comment: So, we have found a complicated description of the identity function.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, in the sequence $e_1,\ldots, e_m$ you can press any button more than once, and pressing $e$ and $e'$ may not commute

Comment: hm, why do not they commute?

Comment: Right - I am wrong, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a sort of generalization of the game 'Lights out'.

There are a few paper's e.g. by M. Zaidenberg
(for example "Periodic harmonic functions on lattices and points count in positive characteristic.")
on the underlying mathematics.

Comment: This seems pretty unrelated. And the comments below the question seem sufficient, in fact.

Comment: No, it is related: it is the special case where the switches are associated to the set of all neighbours and it gives rise to fairly beautiful mathematics involving e.g. elliptic curves over finite fields.